# Data-bind attr mailto, subject and body

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I am wondering how can I get subject and body.

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: 'mailto:' + 'test@test.com', **subject:'test', body:'test'** }">click</a>
```

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also do you need the `attr:` added, ie can you remove it or will it always be there?

Comment: Yes I need to call data.  I can use this href="mailto:xxx@xxx.com?subject=xxx %2&body=xxx  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `email`, `subject`, and `body` are all separate observables in your viewmodel, then you can add a `mailto` computed observable which can combine these for your `href` attribute. For instance:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.email = ko.observable('test@test.com');
    this.subject = ko.observable('test');
    this.body = ko.observable('test');
    this.mailto = ko.computed(function() {
        return 'mailto:' + this.email() + '?subject=' + this.subject() + '&body=' + this.body();
    }, this);
};
```

And then the anchor tag can be setup like so:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: mailto }">click</a>
```